# Merging on multiple conditions in R

Tags: r, matrix, plyr

I have two dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame( pt = c("pt1153", "pt1153", "pt1153", "pt1154", "pt1155", "pt1156"),
                   phys = c("p10", "p616", "p850", "p899", "p709", "p892"))

df2<- data.frame( sender = c("p10", "p10", "p100", "p100", "p102", "p103"),
                  s.type = c(11,11,21,21,11, 21),
                  receiver = c("p616", "p850", "p235", "p388", "p596", "p696"),
                  r.type = c(21,31,11,11,31,31),
                  shared.pts = c(1,1,1,1,1,1) )
```

I want to end up with

```
  sender s.type receiver r.type shared.pts pts
    p10    11    p616     21      1        p1153
    p10    11    p850     31      1        p1153
```

But I can't figure out how to do it.  I tried merging and then using ddply, but that didn't work.  I also tried playing around with apply, but couldn't figure out what function to make.

It's not enough to just merge the dfs. I need to merge them based on each sharing a member of the column "pts" in df1

Though I can't seem to reproduce my problem, when I use merge I end up with:

```
     p.sender.id p.receiver.type Source.total.pts p.receiver.id p.sender.type Target.total.pts shared.pts patient.id
1          p10              21                6          p616            11              3          1     pt2439

2          p10              21                6          p616            11                3          1     pt1870

3          p10              21                6          p616            11                3          1     pt1153

4          p10              21                6          p616            11              3          1       pt64
5          p10              21                6          p616            11              3          1     pt1626
6          p10              21                6          p616            11              3          1      pt941
7          p10              31                6          p850            11             10          1     pt2439
8          p10              31                6          p850            11             10          1     pt1870
9          p10              31                6          p850            11             10          1     pt1153
10         p10              31                6          p850            11               10          1       pt64
```

When p10 and p616 only share one pt. pt1153

Answer (score 2):

I think that merge should work !!

```
merge(df2, df1, by.x = "sender", by.y = "p")
  sender receiver   pts
1    p10     p850 pt800
2    p55      p90  pt11
```

Comment: I should have put more example in my example. This only works because there is only one instance of p10 -> p850. If I had p10, p10, p10, p850, p800 p75, I would get a pt800 for each instance of p10, which is what I'm trying to avoid. I'm going to fix the example

Answer (score 1):

This gets you most of the way there, only the columns aren't in the same order:

```
ddply(df1,.(pts),function(x){ x$p })
    pts  V1   V2
1  pt11 p55  p90
2 pt800 p10 p850
```

But since I only used `df1` I'm suspicious about whether you've left anything out of your question that means you can't employ this strategy with your real data.

Comment: I get this error when I try this method: `Error in list_to_dataframe(res, attr(.data, "split_labels")) :    Results do not have equal lengths`

Comment: @crock1255 I'm not going to spend time on a question that changes after you answer it.

Comment: I didn't realize my example wasn't going to reproduce the same error I was getting. I tried to save some steps with the data entry.  If I wasn't lost on the question, I wouldn't be asking the board. I do appreciate the time though and wouldn't have redone the example if I had realized the answer wasn't going to answer the question I originally wanted it to answer.

Comment: @crock1255 I'm not upset; I'm just sayin': if you want help from complete strangers its best to not make them feel like you're wasting their time. So its wise to put in the effort to make your question good the first time around. I'm moving on, but perhaps someone else will help you.